# What's Standardization, and why do it?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, terminology

Surprisingly, there are very few resources online (outside of obscure lab pages) that explain exactly what standardization is (not even Wikipedia!). The context is the phrase *standardize the titrant* for a titration. Does this mean you titrate it with a known solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagine that you need to titrate the sample **S** with a solution of the reagent **R**.

Unfortunately, **R** isn't available as a stock solution and maybe not even in solid form. All you have is it's precursor **P** and a recipe for the reaction $\ce{P + X + Y -> R}$. You never know how good that works out.

At this point, titration of **S** with **R** doesn't make any sense - unless you can determine the concentration of **R**!

Here, a stock solution with an exact concentration of the helper **H**, maybe in a sealed vial from a commerical source comes into play.

The titration of **R** with **H** to give the exact concentration of the solution of **R** is the *standardization of the titrant*.

Answer (score 1):

> Standardization is doing a titration to work out the exact
>   concentration of *the solution you want to use* to determine the
>   concentration of an unknown solution.

Where *the solution you want to use* is the titrant

See : http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090903183139AAXfQGm

Answer (score 0):

Standardization is the process of determining the accurate concentration of a standard solution by titrating it against a solution of accurate concentration with high degree of purity